# How to prevent your application process from killing by system

Tags: java, android, performance, process

I created an application and I want to make it stable and reliable so it should never stop its working until uninstall, I know that system kills application when running out of the memory. What exactly happens when system kills your application? Is it take all the heap memory from application and left it non functional? or application process are maintained of all application currently installed on phone? How can I make sure that my application won't stop working and system maintain its priority?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to keep your app's background Service or such or the entire app i.e. Task, Window, Activity etc?

Comment: `AFAIK` Android kills the Linux process which your app runs behind scene which is certainly enough to recover some memory and destroys the app. Note: this part requires some level of understanding in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

1. Understanding Android service
   A Service is an application component representing either an application's 
   desire to perform a longer-running operation while not interacting with 
   the user or to supply functionality for other applications to use.
2. Create a Your AndroidService
3. set START_STICKY mode
   If this service's process is killed while it is started (after returning 
   from onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)),

   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

   ```
   return START_STICKY;
   ```

   }